# How to place markup after the submit button in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

goal : I want to place a text after the submit button using hook_form_alter.

Below is my code but if I use the weight key in the array then its postion does move in the form but not below the submit/save button.  What can I do for it to go below the save button ?

```
$xdmp_twoshow="text";

$form['previewxdmp'] = array(
'#type'=>'markup',
'#markup'=>$xdmp_toshow,
'#weight' => 35,
 );
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Each element can have a [`#prefix`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#prefix) and [`#suffix`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#suffix) property which will place text/HTML immediately after the rendered output. With that in mind you can simply attach a suffix to the existing submit button like so:

```
$form['submit']['#suffix'] = '<p>Some text to place after the submit button</p>';
```

Obviously the location of the submit button within the `$form` array might be slightly different depending on the form you're altering.

Comment: thanks , it worked ! Sorry for the delay in the udpate . As was busy with other projects.

Answer (score 1):

I did it as follows:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FROM_ID_alter()
 */
function mymodule_form_mycontenttype_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['actions']['submit']['#suffix'] = '<p>' . t('Some text to place after the submit button.') . '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Submit buttons are usually placed in `$form['actions']` which has the default weight of 100. You can either set the weight of the `$form['actions']` as you like, or give other elements a weight greater than 100 to place them **after** the submit button.

#### Example 1:

**All elements *with `#weight` greater than 34*** will be placed after the submit button (and any other action buttons).

```
$form['actions']['#weight'] = 34;
```

#### Example 2:

**Only the given element** will be placed after the submit button.

```
$form['previewxdmp'] = array(
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => $xdmp_toshow,
  '#weight' => 101,
 );
```